# Problems with VALID padding for Conv2D layer

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I have built the following object recognition model for my school assignment to predict classes from the CIFAR-10 dataset. The assignment requires that I use the VALID padding for all convolution and pooling layers.

```py
def _build_cifar10_model(num_C1_channels=50, num_C2_channels=60, use_dropout=False):
    model = Sequential()
    
    # reshape 1D array of length 3072
    # to a matrix of shape 32x32x3
    model.add(Input(shape=(3072,)))
    model.add(Reshape(target_shape=(32, 32, 3), input_shape=(3072,)))
    
    # 24x24x3
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=num_C1_channels, kernel_size=(9, 9), padding='valid', activation='relu'))
    # 12x12x3
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid'))
    # 8x8x3
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=num_C2_channels, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding='valid', activation='relu'))
    # 4x4x3
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid'))
    
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(units=300))
    if use_dropout:
        model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
    
    model.add(Dense(units=10, activation='softmax'))
    if use_dropout:
        model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
    
    return model
```

However, building this model is throwing the following error:

`InvalidArgumentError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 1 from 0 for '{{node max_pooling2d_15/MaxPool}} = MaxPool[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1]](conv2d_23/Relu)' with input shapes: [?,24,24,0].`

I figured that it is because when padding is VALID, a (32, 32, 3) image becomes size (24, 24, 0) after applying that 1st Conv2D layer with `kernel_size=9` on it. Not sure why the RGB channels are completely lost.

Is there a way to go around this issue while maintaining the VALID padding?

Sorry in advance as this is the first time I am building such a model.

Answer (score 0):

Use `InputLayer` instead of `Input` at the start of your model. It will give you the first layer of the model instead of a symbolic tensor.

Replace the line with this:

```py
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(3072,)))
```

The rest of the code seems to execute for me and gives me a 4x4 layer after the convolution which you feed into your dropout/dense layers.

Comment: Appreciate the reply. I've changed ```model.add(Input(shape=(3072,)))``` to the line ```model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(3072,)))``` and the error seems to still recur.

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/101CqH_cmOAgP8YTBltCzzOqChFGpRM2K?usp=sharing Please see this, it's working for me.

Comment: Restart your environment and run it once, maybe that will solve the issue, because both on my local system and on colab it works smoothly. I am using tensorflow keras and not pure keras, cause it's no longer supported. Please check once that you are doing the same.